# How to only read digits before decimal in javascript?

Tags: javascript, parsing, variables

I have script I am using here: http://jsfiddle.net/6b2yy/1/

It's supposed to change the background color of each individual table depending on the variable value. However, it does not work as it is now because the variables have a decimal and % after them. How can I make it only read the first two digits before the decimal, without changing what is displayed on the page. One thing to note is that on my site those are variables displayed, not static numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function

```
parseInt('75.9%',10)
> 75
```

I guess in your case it would be

```
score = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6b2yy/2/)

Comment: Probably more efficient to use `parseInt(this.textContent || this.innerText), 10);`. Note that in [ES5](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2) the assumption that leading zero is octal has been removed, but browsers still do it (at least FF 15 does).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reading the numbers up to the decimal, why not read and round the value properly?

```
parseInt('75.9%',10);            //-> 75
Math.round(parseFloat('75.9%')); //-> 76
```

Comment: `parseFloat()` doesn't round, and doesn't take a second argument. (Though I agree that rounding 75.9 to 76 via the appropriate methods might make sense.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks; I must have copy/pasted and gotten distracted by lining up the comments. Fixed.